# Generate two different tags in different sub-trees by one match using XSLT 1.0 and Java

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have this input XML:
...

```
<body>
      <wp .../>
  </body>
```

...

I need to generate this XML:
...

```
<body>
<wp-list>
  <from_wp_1 .../>
  ...
</wp-list>
<ro>
  <from_wp_2.../>
  ...
</ro>
</body>
```

...

How can I generate these two different tags from_wp_1 and from_wp_2 in different sub-trees for one input wp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is rather vague, and many different answers are possible. I *think* you want to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <wp-list>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="wp"/>
        </wp-list>
        <ro>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="wp" mode="ro"/>
        </ro>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wp">
    <!-- do something -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wp" mode="ro">
    <!-- do something else -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly!